Why might one get conflicts when trying to rebase or merge in Git from upstream?
I am trying to make sure my local repo and fork are up to date with upstream. However, I am new to git and am stuck. I tried updating my git commands, but I keep getting merge conflicts where I try to merge or rebase. My process is to
Fetch
git fetch upstream

Rebase
git rebase upstream/deploy

Push
git push origin deploy

for each branch of the project.
I did main first. Now when I try to do the same with the other two branches, deploy, and solutions, I get merged conflicts. I stashed my code so nothing (git diff --cached shows no differences) is different when I try to do the rebasing, yet I still get merge conflicts.

I referenced these two other questions for help to no avail: how-do-i-update-or-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github
why-git-rebase-shows-conflicts-in-the-files-i-did-not-modify
I am not sure I should try and fix the merge conflicts because they are from a later commit created by another developer. Would not that mess up the git history? Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Don't do a rebase into a shared tree with work from another developer. Use git merge, fix the conflicts, and commit the resulting merge commit if there's someone else's work -- when you create a merge commit it'll have two parents, one being your starting point's history and the other being the other developer's work. (General rule of thumb: If you need to use a force push into a shared branch, you're Doing It Wrong; as long as you never force-push, you aren't destroying work).

If you're rebasing your own feature branch that has your own work and nobody else's, then and only then rebase can be appropriate -- you lose some of the history of your work, but not the history of the other developer's work. But really, ask your team lead, not a bunch of randos on the internet -- each team will have their own preferred workflows.

(also, in general, any "process" that consists of running fixed commands is a bad foundation -- much better to understand what the commands do and the benefits and pitfalls of their semantics to be able to make a contextually-appropriate decision case-by-case).

To be able to answer this, we need to know what the relation between main, deploy, and solutions was before you rebased main. Please show the history graphs.
